# Chrome/Webkit reflow bug with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, webkit, angularjs-ng-repeat, reflow

I'm pretty new to angularjs and I've stumbled upon a strange bug.

I made a timeline using CSS and HTML, and then used `ng-repeat` to dynamically generate it. However, on Webkit browsers, the timeline isn't displayed correctly.

Unfortunately I can't embed images in my post because my account is new, so I uploaded them here :

Webkit render
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZJZZ.png

However, if I resize the window, open the console or change any CSS properties, the timeline now looks fine : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YB2L.png

It also works flawlessly on Firefox or Safari with no reflow needed.

I've looked into `$scope.$apply`, but that doesn't work because I'm using angular to generate the values, so I can't call it and it should be called automatically by angular anyway.

Please note that if I create the `<ul><li></li></ul>` manually, the timeline displays correctly.

Here's the code sample :

```
    <h1>Relevés</h1>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="batch in batches track by batch.id">
            <span class="date" ng-bind="batch.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD/MM/YY'"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**Also, when this bug occurs, I can see artefacts of the timeline on other partial views when changing pages, and this occurs only on Chrome (without any extension).**